# Hadoop namenode not starting, says file:/// has no athority

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to run hadoop 2.6.0 for windows and I am following this guide

https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows

I have everything setup, all the values are set within the correct xml files.

However, I am running to this error when trying to start my namenode

Invalid URI for NameNode address (checkfs.defaultFS): file:/// has no authority.

This is what I have in my core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://0.0.0.0:19000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

What is going on??

Comment: what is the purpose of running hadoop? Do some development and then deploy the code in a real cluster? If so, you can use the basic setup with no cluster mode.

Comment: No, I need to create a cluster for testing. So far I am just trying to get the example working then actually create a cluster. But I am stuck on starting the namenode. Its strange that the service cannot find the defaultFS name that I had specified inside core-site.xml, maybe its using a different core-site.xml that I am not aware of.

Comment: you don't necessary need a cluster to test. you can test your scripts with the basic setup.

Comment: But I would still need to setup a cluster in the future, I am doing distributed testing so I need this to work on several machines.

Comment: then you should deploy a linux cluster right away. Windows is not very tested on hadoop clusters, even Microsoft is using Linux hadoop clusters. https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/02/19/ubuntu-hortonworks-and-microsoft-big-data-hosted-solution/

Comment: I mean they have created a build for windows, it should work. I need this to work for windows anyways.

Comment: try to format the filesystem again .

Comment: i got it working by downloading premade config files, I'm going to go through these and edit what I need.